# How to secure REST API with Spring Boot and Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I know that securing REST API is widely commented topic but I'm not able to create a small prototype that meets my criteria (and I need to confirm that these criteria are realistic). There are so many options how to secure resources and how work with Spring security, I need to clarify if my needs are realistic.

**My requirements**

- Token based authenticator - users will provide its credentials and get unique and time limited access token. I would like to manage token creation, checking validity, expiration in my own implementation.
- Some REST resources will be public - no need to authenticate at all,
- Some resources will be accessible only for users with administrator rights,
- Other resource will be accessible after authorization for all users.
- I don't want to use Basic authentication
- Java code configuration (not XML)

**Current status**

My REST API works very well, but now I need to secure it. When I was looking for a solution I created a `javax.servlet.Filter` filter:

```
  @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String accessToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);
        Account account = accountDao.find(accessToken);

        if (account == null) {    
            throw new UnauthorizedException();    
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }
```

But this solution with `javax.servlet.filters` doesn't work as I need because there is an issue with exception handling via `@ControllerAdvice` with Spring `servlet dispatcher`.

**What I need**

I would like to know if these criteria are realistic and get any help, how to start  securing REST API with Spring Security. I read many tutorials (e.g. [Spring Data REST + Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security)) but all work in very basic configuration - users with **their credentials are stored in memory** in configuration and I need to work with DBMS and create own authenticator.

**Please give me some ideas how to start.**

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> Token based authentication - users will provide its credentials and get
>   unique and time limited access token. I would like to manage token
>   creation, checking validity, expiration in my own implementation.

Actually, use Filter for token Auth - best way in this case

Eventually, you can create CRUD via Spring Data for managing Token's properties like to expire, etc.

Here is my token filter:
http://pastebin.com/13WWpLq2

And Token Service Implementation

http://pastebin.com/dUYM555E

> Some REST resources will be public - no need to authenticate at all

It's not a problem, you can manage your resources via Spring security config like this: `.antMatchers("/rest/blabla/**").permitAll()`

> Some resources will be accessible only for users with administrator rights,

Take a look at `@Secured` annotation to class. Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminservice")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class AdminServiceController {
```

> The other resource will be accessible after authorization for all users.

Back to Spring Security configure, you can configure your url like this:

```
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/openforall/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/alsoopen/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

> I don't want to use Basic authentication

Yep, via token filter, your users will be authenticated.

> Java code configuration (not XML)

Back to the words above, look at `@EnableWebSecurity`.
Your class will be:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

You have to override the **configure** method. Code below, just for example, how to configure matchers. It's from another project.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .and()
                .csrf();
}
```

Comment: @Oleksandr: Thats a long shot, but can you tell me why you have started a thread in RESTAuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter class's updateLastLogin(...) method?

Comment: @z3d4s, actually it's an old example (4 years), for now i will suggest to use OffsetDateTime, another approaches, etc :)
new thread i proposed to use to decrease processing time for user requests, because it can take additional time during saving into the database.

Answer (score 4):

Spring security also very useful for providing authentication and authorization to the REST URLs. We no need to specify any custom implementations.

First, you need to specify the entry-point-ref to restAuthenticationEntryPoint in your security configuration as below.

```
 <security:http pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" create-session="stateless" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/userList" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/managerList" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

Implementation for the restAuthenticationEntryPoint might be as below.

```
 @Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
      response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
   }
}
```

After this you need to specify RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter. It contains the RequestHeader key. This is basically used for identifying the user`s authentication. Generally RequestHeader carries this information while making the REST calls. 
For example consider below code

```
   <bean id="preAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Authorization"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
  </bean>
```

Here,

```
<property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Authorization"/>
```

"Authorization" is the the key presented the incoming request. It holds the required user`s authentication information.
Also you need to configure the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider to fulfill our requirement.

```
   <bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
  <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="authenticationService"/>
  </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

This code will work for securing the REST urls by means of Authentication and authorization without any custom implementations.

For Complete code please find the below link:

https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-rest-security

Answer (score 0):

I searched this long time too.I am working on a similar project.I found out Spring has a module to implement session via redis. It looks easy and useful.
I will add to my project too. Can be helpful:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/guides/rest.html

Answer (score 0):

### Another way that uses `http.addFilterBefore()` with custom filters

This solution is more like a skeleton to help you set up the basics.
I've created a `working demo` and added some necessary comments to help understand the process. It comes with with some simple `role-based` and `permission-based` authentication/authorization, a `publically accessable endpoint` settings that you can easily pick up and use.

###### So it's better to see the full code, and run the app in action: [github repo](https://github.com/Enfield-Li/SpringSecurity_Rest_API_Simple_Demo)

User class set up:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

  private final String username;
  private final String password;
  private final List<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

  public User(
    String username,
    String password,
    List<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities
  ) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
  }

  // And other default method overrides
}
```

Adding custom filters through `addFilterBefore()` method:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/") 
    .permitAll()
    .addFilterBefore( // Filter login request only
        new LoginFilter("login", authenticationManager()),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    )
    .addFilterBefore( // Filter logout request only
        new LogoutFilter("logout"),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    )
    .addFilterBefore( // Verify user on every request
        new AuthenticationFilter(),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    );
```

Custom `LoginFilter` extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and override three methods, to deal with autentication:

```
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public LoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(url, authManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest req,
    HttpServletResponse res
  )
    throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
    LoginUserDto loginUserDto = new ObjectMapper() // this dto is a simple {username, password} object
    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), LoginUserDto.class);

    return getAuthenticationManager()
      .authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
          loginUserDto.getUsername(),
          loginUserDto.getPassword()
        )
      );
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest req,
    HttpServletResponse res,
    FilterChain chain,
    Authentication auth
  )
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();

    req.getSession().setAttribute(UserSessionKey, user); // Simply put it in session

    res.getOutputStream().print("You are logged in as " + user.getUsername());
  }

  @Override
  protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    AuthenticationException failed
  )
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getOutputStream().print(failed.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Custom `AuthenticationFilter` check for `auth info` stored in session and pass to `SecurityContext`:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(
    ServletRequest request,
    ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain filterChain
  )
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    User user = (User) session.getAttribute(UserSessionKey);

    if (user != null) {
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        user,
        user.getPassword(),
        user.getAuthorities()
      );

      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    }

    // Either securityContext has authToken or not, we continue the filter chain
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Custom `LogoutFilter` is rather simple and straightforward, invalidate session and terminate authentication process:

```
public class LogoutFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public LogoutFilter(String url) {
    super(url);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest req,
    HttpServletResponse res
  )
    throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
    req.getSession().invalidate();
    res.getWriter().println("You logged out!");

    return null;
  }
}
```

#### A bit of explanation:

What these three custom filters do is that, `login` and `logout` filter only listen to their repective endpoint.

In login filter, we get `username and password` sent from client and check it against a DB(in real world) for validation, if it's valid user, then put it in session and pass it onto `SecurityContext`.

In logout filter, we simply `invalidate the session` and return a string.

While the custom `AuthenticationFilter` will authenticate every incomming request in an attempt to get user info from session, and then pass it onto `SecurityContext`.

Answer (score -3):

To validate REST API there are 2 ways

1 - Basic authentication using default username and password set up in application.properties file

[Basic Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-y3FW3_DmA)

2 - Authenticate using database (userDetailsService) with the actual username and password

[Advanced Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6v-LnpUQSs)

Comment: Video is usefull.How to do the same advanced authentication for ReST API. Here only describing about Web. Is there any  video tutorial for advanced authentication in REST API.

Comment: If you saw the 2nd video(Advanced Authentication), then in that I am doing the same authentication using REST client(for REST API) as well.