# How to restrict POST Rest Api for public access after successful login in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, backend

I am a new in JAVA/Springboot,
I want to restrict POST rest api to access publicly.

Once user login successfully, the API is currently accessible publicly and able to add update data.
I want to restrict it and only accessible privately.My aim is to restrict unauthorised user to add or update data publicly and it should be privatly accessible.

Thank You...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure REST API with Spring Boot and Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548372/how-to-secure-rest-api-with-spring-boot-and-spring-security)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of preAuthorize

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('MY_ROLE_TO_CHECK')")
```

preAuthorize also allow you expressions with Spring EL.

if you just want to check, if the user is logged in, then it could be

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

Take a look at [Built-in EL of Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in)

[Enable annotation-based security to use preAuthorize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#enableglobalmethodsecurity)